# Does cooking in a pressure cooker destroy nutrients?

Tags: cookware, pressure-cooker

I've read that because of the higher temperature specially vegetables lose more nutrients in a pressure cooker as opposed to a normal cooking method. Is this true?

Comment: Found 2 interesting links http://www.eatingwell.com/healthy_cooking/healthy_cooking_101_basics_techniques/what_is_the_effect_of_pressure_cooking_on_nutr and http://www.nytimes.com/2008/05/20/health/nutrition/20well.html?_r=0

Comment: Sorry @Stefan Just noticed you found the same reference I did.  I found it when the original question was posted, but didn't add my answer to the site until Rumtscho reopened the question, since I thought it would be closed for off-topic.  Wasn't trying to steal your answer.  I am wiki'ing the answer so that there are no rep issues.

Comment: No issue, we are here to help not to gain rep. I could not write answer since question was closed. I argued that maybe this was a borderline close (my comment have been removed??) and decided to throw in the links that I found just for info.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Eating Well](http://www.eatingwell.com/healthy_cooking/healthy_cooking_101_basics_techniques/what_is_the_effect_of_pressure_cooking_on_nutr) who consulted a food scientist, yes, some heat sensitive nutrients are lost, but no more so than other forms of cooking:

> Pressure cooking can reduce heat-sensitive nutrients (e.g., vitamin C,
>   folate) and bioactive phytonutrients, such as betacarotene,
>   glucosinolates (helpful compounds found in cruciferous vegetables) and
>   omega-3 fatty acids, that are beneficial for human health. But so do
>   other cooking methods—and generally to more or less the same extent.

but in other cases, as in grains and legumes, the pressure-cooking is helpful:

> in the case of grains and legumes, although the vitamins and
>   heat-sensitive vitamins and phytonutrients are vulnerable to
>   deterioration, the net result of pressure-cooking is a positive
>   nutritional gain—from the increased digestibility of the
>   macronutrients (protein, fiber and starch) and the increased
>   bioavailability of the essential minerals.